# Append anchor tags to list html

Tags: html, append, anchor, html-lists

In my javascript am trying to

1) make a new li tag

2) make a new a (anchor tag)

3) append the anchor tag to li tag

4) set the text for anchor tag (so that someone can click on it)

5) set onClick event function for anchor tag (to be called when click is made in 4))

6) append the li tag to a div

And here is my code :

```
var newLi = document.createElement('li');
var newA = document.createElement('a');
newLi.appendChild(newA);
//newA.href='#';
newA.innerText = "Go here";
newA.onClick = function(){
                      // do something here
              }
document.getElementById('map_canvas').appendChild(newLi);
```

Obviusly it is not working and all I see is Just the bullets(as below) on my page with no text and  clickable text (for anchor tags) `<li> <li>`

Comment: It probably isn't the reason, but the property is called `onclick`, not `onClick`. It's more likely that the problem is that `innerText` is IE-specific. What browser are you working in?

Comment: Incidentally, an `li` is an invalid child of a `div` element; it can, so far as I know, only be (validly) placed within an `ol` or `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

just use *innerHTML* instead of *innerText*

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `.innerHTML` in place of `.innerText`, and ideally creating a function:

```
function listLinks(listId, url,text){

    var linkList;
    if (document.getElementById(listId)) {
        linkList = document.getElementById(listId);
    }
    else {
        linkList = document.createElement('ul');
        document.body.appendChild(linkList);
    }
    var newA = document.createElement('a');

    newA.innerHTML = text;
    newA.href = url;
    newA.onclick = function(){
        this.style.color = '#f00'; // or whatever...
        return false;
    };

    var newLi = document.createElement('li');

    newLi.appendChild(newA);

    linkList.appendChild(newLi);
}

// call as:
listLinks('links','http://google.com/','Google');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tSbeJ/2/).